# Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Show that $f(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x) = +\infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}f(x) = -\infty$. Show that $f(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$

Do we begin by showing 0 is contained, and for every $x$, there is $-x$ and an $x_0$ > $x$?

Comment: The intermediate value theorem should come to mind.

Comment: Well, let a be in R.  a is not an upper bound nor a lower bound so there exist $x,y$ so that $f(x) < a < f(y)$ so by intermediate value theorem....  Are are you expected to prove the intermediate value theorem from definitions?

Answer (score 1):

There will always be, for arbitrary $N\in\Bbb N$, points $a<0<b$ with $f(a)<-N$, $f(b)>N$.

Thus $[-N,N]\subset [f(a),f(b)]\subset f([a,b])\subset f(\Bbb R)$ by the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-a$, $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Snce $f(x)$ is continuous also $g(x)$ is continuous and, from the limits for $f(x)$, we have: $\lim_{x\to -\infty}g(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty}g(x)=+\infty$.

So there exists $ M>0$ such that $g(M)>0$ and $g(-M)<0$. Using the [intermedite value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#Proof) in  the interval $[-M,M]$ we find that there is a point $x_0$ such that 
$$
g(x_0)=f(x_0)-a=0
$$

so there is a value $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=a \quad \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$